# understanding haskell random coin generating code

Tags: haskell

Please help me understand the below haskell code.

```
data Coin = Heads | Tails deriving ({-hi-}Eq, {-/hi-} Show,Enum,Bounded)

instance Random Coin where
    randomR (a,b) g =
        case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
          (x,g') -> (toEnum x,g')
    random g = randomR (minBound,maxBound) g

coins = do
    g <- newStdGen
    print . take 10 $ (randoms g::[Coin])

count = 10000

process :: [Coin] -> (Int,Int)
process cs = (length cs,length (filter (== Heads) cs))

display::(Int,Int) -> String
display (coins,heads) = "We got " ++ (show $ 100.0 * fromIntegral heads / fromIntegral coins) ++ "% heads. "

r = do
    g <- newStdGen
    putStrLn . display .process . take count $ randoms g
```

1. I could'nt get what does `{-hi-}Eq, {-/hi-} Show`do mean.
2. and the below, What's the significance of "of" and the next part.

case randomR (fromEnum a, fromEnum b) g of
          (x,g') -> (toEnum x,g')

Comment: {-hi-} is a comment, if this is from a book or wiki page, it could be a broken formatting instruction - the person who wrote the page probably thought it was going to highlight the word "Eq"

Comment: `case ... of` are [Haskell keywords](https://wiki.haskell.org/Keywords#case.2C_of).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Coin` is an algebraic data type with two constructors, `Heads` and `Tails`, representing an enumeration with two values. It’s isomorphic to (has the same structure as) `Bool` but is a distinct type.

`deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)` automatically generates implementations of the typeclasses:

- `Eq`, the class of types that support testing for equality with `==`
- `Show`, for converting values to strings for debugging
- `Enum`, for enumerating values with the predecessor and successor functions `pred` and `succ`
- `Bounded`, types that have a `minBound` (here `Heads`) and `maxBound` (`Tails`)
- `{-`…`-}` is just a comment, which is ignored by the compiler; it appears the author intended to use some kind of non-Haskell formatting notation that didn’t work properly.

`instance Random Coin where` begins an implementation of the `Random` typeclass for the `Coin` type, enabling random generation of coins. It has implementations for two methods:

- `randomR (a, b) g` describes how to generate a random value in the range `a` to `b` using the random generator `g`. The implementation calls `randomR` to generate a random *integer* in the range of the parameters `a` and `b` using the `Enum` class. If `a` is `Heads` then `fromEnum a` is `0`; if `b` is `Tails` then `fromEnum b` is `1`. The `case`…`of` notation performs a *pattern match* on the result of this function, getting a pair of a random value `x` and an updated random generator `g'` (pronounced “G prime”). It then converts `x` from an integer back into a `Coin` using `toEnum`, and returns the coin value along with the updated generator.
- `random` describes how to generate a random coin from just a generator, without taking the range as input. It generates a coin toss between `minBound` (`Heads`) and `maxBound` (`Tails`) using the given generator `g`.

`coins` is an `IO` action that creates a new standard random generator with `newStdGen`, then generates an infinite list (stream) of random coin tosses from that generator with `randoms g :: [Coin]`. It uses `take` to grab the first 10 elements of that list and outputs them with `print`.

`r` is similar to `coins`, but also runs the coin tosses through the `process` function, which returns a pair of the number of coins it was given (`length cs`) and the number of those that are `Heads` (`length (filter (== Heads) cs)`); and the `display` function which formats the result as a string percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a rewritten version with some unnecessary things removed:

```
module Coin where

import System.Random

data Coin = Tails | Heads deriving (Eq)
```

Here the `Coin` data type is defined. The derived `Eq` type class instance means that you can compare two coins for equality using `==`, useful for counting how many `Heads` you got. I've removed `Show` because it was never used in this snippet, although it's quite neat. I've removed `Enum` and `Bounded` for demonstrative purposes.

```
instance Enum Coin where
  toEnum 0 = Tails
  toEnum 1 = Heads
  fromEnum Tails = 0
  fromEnum Heads = 1
```

In your code, this was achieved by adding `Enum` to the list of derived type class instances: It means that from now on, you can take any coin and convert it to an `Int` (0 or 1), and you can take an `Int` (0 or 1) and convert it to a `Coin`. Automatic derivation is neater, but this spells out what exactly that `Enum` means.

```
instance Bounded Coin where
  minBound = Tails
  maxBound = Heads
```

In your code, this was achieved by adding `Bounded` to the list of derived type class instances: It means that the "smallest" `Coin` value is `Tails`, and the "greatest" `Coin` value is `Heads`. This might not make any sense except when generating random coins.

```
instance Random Coin where
  randomR (coin1, coin2) gen =
    case randomR (fromEnum coin1, fromEnum coin2) gen of
      (x, gen') -> (toEnum x, gen')
  random gen = randomR (minBound, maxBound) gen
```

Here we say that we can generate random `Coin`s using the standard random value generator library. According to [the `Random` type class definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html), the *minimal complete definition* is `randomR` and `random`, meaning that you can use all the random functions in relation to generating random coins if you define only these two. (The remaining random functions are defined in terms of these two.)

- `randomR` takes two things: A range `(coin1, coin2)` and a random generator `gen` and returns a tuple `(toEnum x, gen')` meaning: a random coin `toEnum x` and an updated random generator `gen'`. The random coin should be in the range of `coin1` and `coin2`, which sounds kind of weird because there are only two values. (If you didn't want the full range of `(Tails, Heads)`, you'd know exactly which coin you got.) But for integers, generating a random value in a range makes sense, and the random generator library is intended for data types with any number of constructors, not just two.

  The actual random generation is performed by relying on the existing random number generator for `Int`s by saying: Generating a random `Heads`/`Tails` is just like generating a random `Int` (0 or 1) and then mapping that back to coins. This is where the `Enum` type class comes handy.
- `random` takes only one thing: A random generator `gen`. It then does the same as `randomR` except it supplies the full range of values. `minBound` and `maxBound` are fancy ways of saying `Tails` and `Heads` because [the `Bounded` type class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bounded) instance provides names for the minimum and the maximum values. But we could just have written `Tails` and `Heads`.

  The advantage og using a derived `Bounded` class and write `minBound` and `maxBound` instead is that you can extend the data type with a third option without having to change the `Random` instance -- if you forgot (there would be no warning), your random generator would just never generate all three options.

If you didn't want the `Enum` and `Bounded` type class instances, you could write `Random` in a much simpler, less maintainable way, in which the conversion between `Coin` and `Int` happens inside the definition for `randomR`, and the minimum and maximum bounds for the type are just hardcoded as `Tails` and `Heads` respectively:

```
instance Random Coin where
  randomR (Tails, Heads) gen =
    case randomR (0, 1) gen of
      (0, gen') -> (Tails, gen')
      (1, gen') -> (Heads, gen')
  randomR (someCoin, _) gen = (someCoin, gen)
  random gen = randomR (Tails, Heads) gen
```

Here we don't rely on `toEnum`, `fromEnum`, `minBound` or `maxBound`, and we abuse the wording in the `randomR` documentation: *It is unspecified what happens if lo>hi,* meaning if we're not generating a random coin in exactly the interval `(Tails, Heads)`, then we're either in the *lo=hi* cases of `(Heads, Heads)` or `(Tails, Tails)` in which case we don't need randomness, because there's only one value to draw from, or we're in the unspecified case of *lo>hi* in which case we also just return the first value in the interval. (In the code using `Enum` and `Bounded`, the responsibility of dealing with a nonsensical range was just passed on to the random `Int` number generator which does much the same thing.)